# Add content-type for specific file types in Amazon CloudFront for APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, content-type

I have an Express app on a Lambda function behind APIGateway. I'm able to access the website and https://example.com.com/robots.txt . When I put a Cloudfront distribution in front of API Gateway I can still access the website but not the robots.txt file: https://example.com/robots.txt
How can I make this content-type discoverable when using Cloudfront with API Gateway?

So far, in addition to my default behaviour in my Cloudfront Distribution I've created a behaviour for `/*.txt` with a response header policy and attached it to my distribution. However it still doesn't allow me to access the robots.txt file on the site.

Behaviour for `/*.txt`

[image: Behaviour for /*.txt]

Response header policy for `Content-Type: text/plain`

[image: Response header policy for Content-Type: text/plain]

Behaviour attached to distribution

[image: Behaviour attached to distribution]

Comment: you're able to access https://example.com/robots.txt directly but not able to access with cloudfront domain, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I put Cloudfront there to redirect any http traffic to https

Comment: What error you are getting when you try accessing /robots.txt ? can you see if the request is reaching to API gateway?

Comment: It seems to not catch the robot.txt, with the current setup above I get the homepages html, I think this is because of the response header policy. If I remove the response header policy I just get the homepage rendered. I'm using aws-serverless-express now known as @vendia/serverless-express.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of what you get? What is the return status code of /robots.txt. It is strange if robots.txt redirects to say homepages.html pages. Could it be the content of robots.txt ~is~ html.

Comment: Instead of adding custom header policies for `.txt`, maybe try adding an integration response to your API Gateway method.

Comment: The return status code is 200 for the robots.txt, the page shows the homepages html.

Comment: have you given thought to serving robots.txt from the S3 bucket directly, so you have your API gateway origin which is serving all the other routes and another custom origin for the S3 bucket which will serve robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Create an Origin with API Gateway endpoint, look into the below screenshot.

**Origin:**
[image: Cloudfront Origin]

and In Behaviours

- Add Path Pattern `/*.txt`
- Compress objects automatically: No
- Viewer protocol policy `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`
- Allowed HTTP methods `GET, HEAD`
- Restrict viewer access: No
- Created and Attached Response headers policy same as yours.
- Didn't modify any Additional settings

Refer to the screenshot below.
**Behavior:**
[image: Cloudfront Behaviour]

With the above config, I'm able to access `robots.txt` successfully, which is being fetched from Lambda.

If you're still getting the issues, then it should be a problem from API Gateway or Lambda, definitely, it's not from Cloudfront.

Comment: You left out the response header policy, or is it the same as mine?

Comment: I've set same as yours